# sql script repository

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am a fresh DBA just being promoted, I am looking for few good sites which constains T-sql Scripts for DBA tasks. Is there a common place from where you can get a collection scripts to perform operation like tuning, re-indexing, DMV, restore, mirror etc.

regards Thanks for listening

Answer (score 4):

This might be a good start: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Scripts/

Answer (score 3):

Another good place would be [SQLServerPedia's TSQL Library](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10040.transact-sql-code-library.aspx) (now migrated to a new domain).

Answer (score 3):

I tend to favor Google or Bing as my script repository.

A few folks also have dedicated scripts that are used for mutliple things when it comes to DBA tasks. One is Adam Machanic and his [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com). Then there is Ola Hallengren and his [maitenance script](http://ola.hallengren.com/). Both of these are probably the most used tools a SQL Server DBA can have available. They are both kept up-to-date with each release of SQL Server as well.